# Type Conversion and Type Conversion Constructors In c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A;

class B{
private:
    int j=0;
    int i;
public:
    B (const A& tempA){
        cout<<"B construct from A"<<endl;
    }
    B(){}
};

class A{
public:
    friend class B;
    A(){};
    A& operator=(const A& temp){
        cout<<"operator= overloaded"<<endl;
        this->value=temp.value;
        return *this; 
    }
    operator B() const{
        cout<<"B cast"<<endl;
        return B();
    }
    ~A(){};
private:
    int value=0;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    B b;
    b=a;
}
```

The program outputs the following:

> B construct from A

Why does the compiler choose to construct a new temporary B (using `B (const A& tempA)`) instead of converting `a` to type `B` (using `operator B() const`)?

Comment: Ambiguous for gcc/clang [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ns4E3qxG9).

Comment: Ambiguous on my machine.  Can be un-ambiguous-ified by changing to either `b=a.operator B();` or `b=B{a};`.

Comment: @Eljay
GCC or Clang?

Comment: @Jarod42 
what does " -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unknown-pragmas"mean? if Idelete this,it will not be ambiguous for gcc in the website that you offered.(I am using gcc )

Comment: `-W*` are extra warnings. `-pedantic` turns off some extensions.

Comment: @Jarod42
so some extensions resulted in no ambiguity in my program ？

Comment: I didn't identify the extension changing that overload resolution. but yes (might be a side effect of that extension BTW).

Comment: Worked with both clang++ 16.0.6 and g++ 13.1.0.